# Upload file from html when block public access is true

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using `django-s3direct` to file upload

`https://github.com/bradleyg/django-s3direct`

Using IAM role setting because I upload the file from the server on ECS container.

Now I set the `blockPublicAccess` of `S3` false.

When uploading images from html, there comes error.

```
https://s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/static-resource-v/images/c64d6e593de44aa5b10dcf1766582547/_origin.jpg?uploads (403 (Forbidden)
)

initiate error: static-resource-v/line-assets/images/c64d6e593de44aa5b10dcf1766582547/_origin.jpg AWS Code: AccessDenied, Message:Access Deniedstatus:403
```

OK, it is understandable.

Browser try to access the for initiation.

However there is any way to upload file from browser when blockPublicAccess is true??

Comment: Use pre-signed s3 urls for uploads.

Comment: is the django-s3direct upload the file from the browser or from your server (first step of course the browser) ?

Comment: @Sandor Bakos From browser. Server is located in ECS though.

Comment: @Marcin mmm I am learning about pre-signed s3 now, still vague..

Comment: Its the only way. So pre-signed urls or make your bucket public (terrible idea). Otherwise have some proxy, e.g. upload file using a lambda function through API gateway.

Comment: Why don't you upload the files to the server and from there to the S3 - you can restrict your bucket in that case, not to be public, and the ecs can have a iam role to upload it to the bucket.

Comment: I checked the package, I think this is how it works Browser -> Form Request -> Server -> S3

Comment: @whitebear I think for uploading the files on backend you can use django-storages and if you want to directly upload from frontend then first you need to generate s3 presigned url and then upload the file with that presigned url.

Comment: Thank you very much, I decide to use `presigned_url`